# jQuery Call resize window on load

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to center a div on my page using jquery and the core code works fine, it centers the div when the page is resized. However I need it resized for load, so I'm calling `$(window).reize();` right after the custom code but for some reason it's only working if you resize the page, not when the page loads.

Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>TEST PAGE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <script>

        $(window).resize(function()
                         {

        $('.mainContent').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.mainContent').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('.mainContent').outerHeight())/2
        });

        });

        // To initially run the function:
        $(window).resize();

    </script>

    <body>

        <div class="mainContent">
        This is a test

        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your src attribute.If you are trying to reference an online script Just replace your src with (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js) and then you can go ahead with ready function.I tried your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes this was the answer. jQuery wasn't loading right. Which is strange as that line of code was taken directly (copy and paste) from Google's CDN page for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

use **[ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**
set your code in  `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $(window).resize(function()
                         {

        $('.mainContent').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.mainContent').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('.mainContent').outerHeight())/2
        });

        });

        // To initially run the function:
        $(window).resize();

});
```

Comment: Even stranger now that works but only centers vertically on load, but then centers vertically and horizontally when you resize the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can just trigger the resize right after the ending like below:

```
$(window).resize(function()
                         {

        $('.mainContent').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.mainContent').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('.mainContent').outerHeight())/2
        });

        }).resize();
```

Comment: Yup it just doesn't seem to want to do it when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Place the script in body tag and then proceed with ready function and check whether it's working or not?

Comment: When placed inside the body tags same result as below. Works when resizing but not on load.